# Chromium's extensions hiding in a menu

Tags: chromium

After adding then removing a fourth extension from my panel in Chromium, all but the first extension are hidden in a menu like so:

[image]

I've tried dragging the address bar to the left and the icons reappear, but the bar snaps back when I let go.

Comment: Is there a link "show button" at the bottom of those extensions in the extension page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your image , it appears that you are using a development version of Chromium.

You can simply click and resize as in this picture:

[image]

---

**See how my extensions look like after dragging the bar to the left:**

[image]

**Now to the right:**

[image]

---

**Note that you can hide any extensions that you don't want:**

[image]

And you can restore it back , from the extensions, in the wrench menu.

**Edit**: I missed that you have tried to drag it. I used to have this problem. 
What I did is that I hid all of the extensions and enabled them again from the extensions settings.

Also make sure to have the latest daily updates. Otherwise switch to a stable version. ( because maybe it's a bug).